# Sending Jinja2 data to another js file -- flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a js file that graphs a function with all the necessary parameters. I wish to do something like this in html:

```
<script  src="js/index2.js" value = {{GraphData}}></script>
```

the js file looks something like this

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "graphs": [{
  "id": "g3",
  "valueAxis": "v1",
   ...
   }],
  "Data" = {{GraphData}} 
})
```

Is there a way to transfer the graph data to the js file?

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here about the function of the script tag.  "value" is not a valid attribute of the HTML script tag, which is used to import the text contents of a JavaScript file into your HTML file.

To achieve what you want, you can simply remove:

```
<script src="js/index2.js" value = {{GraphData}}></script>
```

and replace it with what you want imported:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "graphs": [{
  "id": "g3",
  "valueAxis": "v1",
  ...
  }],
  "Data" = {{GraphData}}  
})
```

More info on the HTML script tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp).

If you want to keep this script external, then you can use it to define a function that takes {{GraphData}} as an argument like this:

```
function graphData(gd) {
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "graphs": [{
    "id": "g3",
    "valueAxis": "v1",
    ...
    }],
    "Data" = gd  
  });
}
```

and then call that function in your HTML file like this:

```
<script src="js/index2.js"></script>
<script>
  graphData({{GraphData}})
</script>
```